# How to add wallpapers to Kindle Fire?

Tags: wallpaper, amazon-kindle-fire

Where do I add/delete pictures so the Kindle Fire will randomly select it as a wallpaper for the device?

Answer (score 4):

Someone over at the XDA Forums already discovered how to do that. See link to the thread below.

I strongly advise to follow this guide only if you know your way around the procedures mentioned (repacking & zipaligning an APK file, file system operations with root permissions) and wouldn't mind jumping through several hoops to recover your device if the process fails.

[XDA Thread - [Guide]Changing Kindle Wallpapers!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355267)

Answer (score 0):

The free app, [My Kindle Wallpaper](https://kindlecooltricks.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/change-kindle-fire-wallpaper-without-rooting/) does this simply and easily, no root required.  D/l & install it, and point it at a photo or a folder full (on the KF, not on the net), and get your favorite background photo or cycle through several (one per wake-up, the way the stock software does).  Works perfectly on my original KF with KF v6.3.1.

(I know it's a year later but this works, no f**ting around, nothing to break. It's literally a download and go. Kudos to the author!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuickPic plus ES File Manager to customize the Kindle Fire wallpaper. Both are free.

The key point is actually that the Kindle Fire system will restore the default wallpaper by default. That's why ES File Manager is indispensable.

Note that the device must have been rooted.

> 1. QuickPic is an efficient picture viewer. It allows you to set any picture as wallpaper. [Click here to download QuickPic](http://quickpic.en.uptodown.com/android).
> 2. Open QuickPic and choose a picture which you want to set as wallpaper. Tap the picture and then tap the top right corner of the window. Choose "Set as" option in the drop-down menu.
>
>    Drag the box to adjust the wallpaper size. Click "save" and it will be saved and set as wallpaper.
>
>    Until this step, you may not find anything different as these are normal operation. If you just lock the screen as you did before and want to see the new wallpaper (I mean "if", please don't lock the screen now), you'll find the new custom wallpaper doesn't work. The boring original wallpaper comes into your eyes again!
>
>    This is due to the fact the system will set the original wallpaper as new wallpaper forcedly every time you lock the screen. So we need to revoke the system's "write" permission so that it can't modify any data again.
>
>    Remember not to lock the screen before step 3!
> 3. Open ES File Explorer and navigate to this path: `/data/data/com.android.settings/files/`. You can find a file called "wallpaper". Press on it and choose "More" – "Properties".
>
>    Choose "Permission" and tap "change". Revoke the "write" permission of "Owner" and "Group" (They have write permission by default). Tap "OK" to confirm revoking.
>
>    Now the system won't modify the wallpaper any more. Lock the screen and press the power button, you'll find the custom wallpaper works!
>
>    Next time you change the wallpaper, please restore the "write" permission of "Owner" and "Group" first, then revoke it after you set wallpaper.

<sup>(Quoted from [epubor](http://www.epubor.com/how-to-change-kindle-fire-wallpaper.html))</sup>